# Insert into mysql database from html form without redirecting

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm working with a mysql database and a webpage that i'm trying to make comunicate with it.

Here's my situation:

i have the `listmat.php` file that echoes all the records in the table `Material` and it works.

Now i manage to show the output of the `listmat.php` file inside a specific `div` witouth refreshing the hole page with the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#matbutton").click(function(){
    $("#matins").load('listmat.php');
  });
});
</script>
```

Where `matbutton` is the id of the submit button in the form and `matins` is the id of the `div` where i show the output of `listmat.php`

Here's my form:

```
<form id="formmatins" method="post" action="listmat.php">
<p>Name:<input type="text" Name="Mat" id="Material"></p>
<center><input type="submit" value="Insert/Remove" id="matbutton"></center>`
</form>
```

What i'd like to do is to use the `matbutton` to also insert the value of the textbox in the table that `listmat.php` echoes all his records. So that everytime i click a record is inserted and in the div is shown the new table

The problem is that if i insert the button in the form with the method post , by clicking it redirects to the output changing page but if i put it out the echoes work but i cannot pass obviously the value of the textbox to the `listmat.php` file to be the argument of the insert because the button is not interested by the method post.

I looked around and looks like the solution is using some articulated structure in jquery/ajax but i really don't know how to fix. Any help would be really appreciated

## UPDATE

```
<script>
  $(function () {

    $('#formmatins').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'listmat.php',
        data: $('#formmatins').serialize(),
        success: function () {
        $("#matins").load('listmat.php');
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

And again it switch page

## UPDATE

```
<?php
$user = "**";
$pass = "**";
$db = "**";
$host = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
$m = $_POST['Mat']; //the text box in the form
$ins = $con->query("INSERT INTO mattemp (Material) VALUES ('$m')");
$query = $con->query("SELECT Material FROM mattemp");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row['Material']."<br>";
    }
?>
```

It print the table updated everytime but still in a new page...what am i doing wrong?

## SOLVED BY MYSELF

Thanks to all have tried to help me. The solution that gave me -1 on the post was not correct and here the solution of my code , in case someone would encounter the same problem

```
`<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#matbutton').on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'listmat.php',
        data: $('#formmatins').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
        $("#matins").load('listmat.php');}
      });

    });

  });
</script>`
```

Comment: There are TONNS of duplicates of that question, learn to use Google

Comment: i think this is different because it calls two different function, a diplay value in a div and an insert into table

Comment: `$('#formmatins').on('submit', function (e) {` it's missing the `#` so is `data: $('formmatins').serialize(),`

Comment: done , nothing changed

Comment: Looks like e.preventDefault() not working...everything goes ok in the php file the problem is the echo of the table is getting shown in a new page (the page relative to the php file) and not in the div

Comment: Nothing yet? Marked as already answerd but still no answer..if my answer is duplicate why no solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

For exemple :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your_url.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#formmatins').serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        // Do something, or not...
    }
})
```